Minecraft Forge 1.19 Including Java Packages
I have following build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'net.minecraftforge.gradle' version '5.1.+'
}

version = '0.0.1-1.19'
group = 'net.roditu.mymod'
archivesBaseName = 'mymod'

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)

println "Java: ${System.getProperty 'java.version'}, JVM: ${System.getProperty 'java.vm.version'} (${System.getProperty 'java.vendor'}), Arch: ${System.getProperty 'os.arch'}"

jarJar.enable()

minecraft {
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'mymod'

            mods {
                mymod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'mymod'

            mods {
                mymod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        gameTestServer {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'mymod'

            mods {
                mymod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            args '--mod', 'mymod', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')

            mods {
                mymod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repository.graalvm.org/graal-release' }
}

dependencies {
    minecraftLibrary 'org.graalvm.js:js:22.3.0'
    minecraftLibrary 'org.graalvm.js:js-scriptengine:22.3.0'

    jarJar(group: 'org.graalvm.js', name: 'js', version: '[22.3.0,22.4.0)')
    jarJar(group: 'org.graalvm.js', name: 'js-scriptengine', version: '[22.3.0,22.4.0)')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : "mymod",
                "Specification-Vendor"    : "mymodsareus",
                "Specification-Version"   : "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : "mymodsareus",
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file://${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' // Use the UTF-8 charset for Java compilation
}

I want to include graalvm java packages into my mod to do:
import org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException
...

In order to do that I added:
minecraftLibrary 'org.graalvm.js:js:22.3.0'
minecraftLibrary 'org.graalvm.js:js-scriptengine:22.3.0'

in dependencies block
that worked just fine when I built and did runClient forgegradle run, but when I tried to use the actual generated .jar file under build/libs and run it with my Minecraft on Forge 1.19.4 the game launched, but when I used the mod I got: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/polyglot/PolyglotException.
The graalvm was not there, the .jar file itself was just 27kB, so I tried to add these packages into the .jar file by adding the following as from Forge's documentation https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/fg-5.x/dependencies/jarinjar/:
jarJar.enable()

jarJar(group: 'org.graalvm.js', name: 'js', version: '[22.3.0,22.4.0)')
jarJar(group: 'org.graalvm.js', name: 'js-scriptengine', version: '[22.3.0,22.4.0)')

That did indeed increase the size of the .jar file as if packages were there, by generating a second .jar file that was 23mB in size, but when I launched Minecraft it crashed before loading the main screen with error code: 1.
I also tried .jar with just one of these packages (just one selected jarJar(...))
Here are logs from that crash as well:
debug.log:
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found naming services : [srgtomcp]
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchPluginHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch plugins: [mixin,eventbus,slf4jfixer,object_holder_definalize,runtime_enum_extender,capability_token_subclass,accesstransformer,runtimedistcleaner]
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Discovering transformation services
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found additional transformation services from discovery services: 
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found transformer services : [mixin,fml]
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services loading
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loading service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loaded service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loading service fml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.LauncherVersion/CORE]: Found FMLLauncher version 1.0
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML 1.0 loading
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found ModLauncher version : 10.0.8+10.0.8+main.0ef7e830
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found AccessTransformer version : 8.0.4+66+master.c09db6d7
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found EventBus version : 6.0.3+6.0.3+master.039e4ea9
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found Runtime Dist Cleaner
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found CoreMod version : 5.0.1+15+master.dc5a2922
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found ForgeSPI package implementation version 6.0.0+6.0.0+master.42474703
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found ForgeSPI package specification 5
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loaded service fml
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Configuring option handling for services
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services initializing
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initializing transformation service mixin
[mixin/]: MixinService [ModLauncher] was successfully booted in cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader@66d18979
[main/INFO] [mixin/]: SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8.5 Source=union:/C:/Users/disen/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/spongepowered/mixin/0.8.5/mixin-0.8.5.jar%2397!/ Service=ModLauncher Env=CLIENT
[mixin/]: Initialising Mixin Platform Manager
[mixin/]: Adding mixin platform agents for container ModLauncher Root Container(ModLauncher:4f56a0a2)
[mixin/]: Instancing new MixinPlatformAgentMinecraftForge for ModLauncher Root Container(ModLauncher:4f56a0a2)
[mixin/]: MixinPlatformAgentMinecraftForge rejected container ModLauncher Root Container(ModLauncher:4f56a0a2)
[mixin/]: Instancing new MixinPlatformAgentDefault for ModLauncher Root Container(ModLauncher:4f56a0a2)
[mixin/]: MixinPlatformAgentDefault accepted container ModLauncher Root Container(ModLauncher:4f56a0a2)
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initialized transformation service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initializing transformation service fml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Setting up basic FML game directories
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path GAMEDIR is C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path MODSDIR is C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path CONFIGDIR is C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\config
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path FMLCONFIG is C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\config\fml.toml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Loading configuration
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Preparing ModFile
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Preparing launch handler
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: Using forgeclient as launch service
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: Received command line version data  : VersionInfo[forgeVersion=45.3.3, mcVersion=1.19.4, mcpVersion=20230314.122934, forgeGroup=net.minecraftforge]
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initialized transformation service fml
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Current naming domain is 'srg'
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Identified name mapping providers {}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services begin scanning
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Beginning scan trigger - transformation service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: End scan trigger - transformation service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Beginning scan trigger - transformation service fml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Initiating mod scan
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModListHandler/CORE]: Found mod coordinates from lists: []
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModDiscoverer/CORE]: Found Mod Locators : (mods folder:null),(maven libs:null),(exploded directory:null),(minecraft:null),(userdev classpath:null)
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModDiscoverer/CORE]: Found Dependency Locators : (JarInJar:null)
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\mymod-0.0.1-1.19-all.jar
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file mymod-0.0.1-1.19-all.jar with {mymod} mods - versions {0.0.1-1.19}
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file client-1.19.4-20230314.122934-srg.jar with {minecraft} mods - versions {1.19.4}
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlcore\1.19.4-45.3.3\fmlcore-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar
[main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlcore\1.19.4-45.3.3\fmlcore-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\javafmllanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\javafmllanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar
[main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\javafmllanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\javafmllanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\lowcodelanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar
[main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\lowcodelanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\mclanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\mclanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar
[main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\mclanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\mclanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.19.4-45.3.3\forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar with {forge} mods - versions {45.3.3}
 [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from client-1.19.4-20230314.122934-srg.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from mclanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from javafmllanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from fmlcore-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from lowcodelanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from js-22.3.5.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractJarFileDependencyLocator/]: Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from js-scriptengine-22.3.5.jar, it does not contain dependency information.
[main/INFO] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.JarInJarDependencyLocator/]: Found 2 dependencies adding them to mods collection
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file client-1.19.4-20230314.122934-srg.jar with {minecraft} mods - versions {1.19.4}
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Loading mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraft\client\1.19.4-20230314.122934\client-1.19.4-20230314.122934-srg.jar with languages [LanguageSpec[languageName=minecraft, acceptedVersions=1]]
[10wrz2024 12:56:22.143][net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.19.4-45.3.3\forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar with {forge} mods - versions {45.3.3}
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Loading mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.19.4-45.3.3\forge-1.19.4-45.3.3-universal.jar with languages [LanguageSpec[languageName=javafml, acceptedVersions=[24,]]]
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Found coremod field_to_method with Javascript path coremods/field_to_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Found coremod field_to_instanceof with Javascript path coremods/field_to_instanceof.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Found coremod add_bouncer_method with Javascript path coremods/add_bouncer_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Found coremod intrinsic_tag_appender_binary_compat with Javascript path coremods/intrinsic_tag_appender_binary_compat.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Found coremod method_redirector with Javascript path coremods/method_redirector.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Found coremod coremods/field_to_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Found coremod coremods/field_to_instanceof.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Found coremod coremods/add_bouncer_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Found coremod coremods/intrinsic_tag_appender_binary_compat.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Found coremod coremods/method_redirector.js
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Considering mod file candidate C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\mymod-0.0.1-1.19-all.jar
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo/LOADING]: Found valid mod file mymod-0.0.1-1.19-all.jar with {mymod} mods - versions {0.0.1-1.19}
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Loading mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\mymod-0.0.1-1.19-all.jar with languages [LanguageSpec[languageName=javafml, acceptedVersions=[41,)]]
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Loading mod file  with languages []
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile/LOADING]: Loading mod file  with languages []
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: End scan trigger - transformation service fml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.LanguageLoadingProvider/CORE]: Found 3 language providers
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.LanguageLoadingProvider/CORE]: Found language provider minecraft, version 1.0
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.LanguageLoadingProvider/CORE]: Found language provider lowcodefml, version 45
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.LanguageLoadingProvider/CORE]: Found language provider javafml, version 45
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.ModSorter/]: Configured system mods: [minecraft, forge]
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.ModSorter/]: Found system mod: minecraft
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.ModSorter/]: Found system mod: forge
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.ModSorter/LOADING]: Found 2 mod requirements (2 mandatory, 0 optional)
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.ModSorter/LOADING]: Found 0 mod requirements missing (0 mandatory, 0 optional)
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services loading transformers
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initializing transformers for transformation service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initialized transformers for transformation service mixin
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initializing transformers for transformation service fml
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Loading coremod transformers
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: Loading CoreMod from coremods/field_to_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: CoreMod loaded successfully
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: Loading CoreMod from coremods/field_to_instanceof.js
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: CoreMod loaded successfully
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: Loading CoreMod from coremods/add_bouncer_method.js
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: CoreMod loaded successfully
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: Loading CoreMod from coremods/intrinsic_tag_appender_binary_compat.js
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: CoreMod loaded successfully
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: Loading CoreMod from coremods/method_redirector.js
[net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine/COREMOD]: CoreMod loaded successfully
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@4da39ca9 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/biome/Biome;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@6ef60295 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/Structure;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@3127cb44 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/effect/MobEffectInstance;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@3234474 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/block/LiquidBlock;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@631cb129 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/item/BucketItem;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@3d20e575 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/block/StairBlock;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@3252747e to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/block/FlowerPotBlock;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@2b4b96a4 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/item/ItemStack;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@2dd8ff1d to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/network/play/client/CClientSettingsPacket;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@17e9bc9e to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraftforge/common/extensions/IForgeIntrinsicHolderTagAppender;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/server/commands/SummonCommand;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/templatesystem/StructureTemplate;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/structures/OceanMonumentPieces$OceanMonumentPiece;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/ai/village/VillageSiege;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/monster/Evoker$EvokerSummonSpellGoal;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/server/commands/RaidCommand;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/NaturalSpawner;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/structures/OceanRuinPieces$OceanRuinPiece;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/npc/Villager;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/animal/frog/Tadpole;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/PatrolSpawner;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/raid/Raid;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/structures/SwampHutPiece;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/PhantomSpawner;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/npc/CatSpawner;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/animal/horse/SkeletonTrapGoal;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/EntityType;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/monster/ZombieVillager;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/monster/Strider;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/structures/WoodlandMansionPieces$WoodlandMansionPiece;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/monster/Spider;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformStore/MODLAUNCHER]: Adding transformer net.minecraftforge.coremod.transformer.CoreModClassTransformer@36b9cb99 to Target : CLASS {Lnet/minecraft/world/entity/monster/Zombie;} {} {V}
[cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initialized transformers for transformation service fml

latest.log:
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlcore\1.19.4-45.3.3\fmlcore-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\javafmllanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\javafmllanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\lowcodelanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\mclanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\mclanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file
[net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.JarInJarDependencyLocator/]: Found 2 dependencies adding them to mods collection

It would appear as errors like this:
Failed to load resource META-INF\jarjar\metadata.json from js-scriptengine-22.3.5.jar, it does not contain dependency information.

Mod file C:\Users\disen\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.19.4-45.3.3\lowcodelanguage-1.19.4-45.3.3.jar is missing mods.toml file

are causing the issue, but how to go about fixing that?
